# MySQL can't delete from web app

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a dynamic table to show all entries in a db table. each row has a delete button where i suppose i can click on any of them to delete an entry in the database. But it's not working. I can delete from phpmyadmin though. here's my php and sql codes:

```
<?php

@$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'xxxx', 'xxx', 'WARD');
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo 'Error: Could not connect to database.  Please try again later.';
    exit;
}

$query       = "SELECT * FROM PATIENT";
$result      = $db->query($query);
$num_results = $result->num_rows;

echo "
<form action=\"dbmgmt.php\" method=\"post\">
";
echo "
<table data-role=\"table\" id=\"table-column-toggle\" data-mode=\"columntoggle\" class=\"ui-responsive table-stroke\">
<thead>
<tr>
<th data-priority=\"2\">
Patient_ID
</th>
<th>
Patient Name
</th>
<th data-priority=\"3\">
Patient IC
</th>
<th data-priority=\"1\">
Phone
</th>
<th data-priority=\"5\">
Address
</th>
<th data-priority=\"5\">
Date Admit
</th>
<th data-priority=\"5\">
Date Discharge
</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
";
echo "
</form>
";
//This form is for submission of gymid to the reservation page.
echo "
<form action=\"dbmgmt.php\" method=\"post\">
";
for ($i = 0; $i < $num_results; $i++) {
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

    if (stripslashes($row['Patient_ID']) == !0) {
        echo "
<tr>
" . PHP_EOL;
        echo "
<td align=\"center\">
" . stripslashes($i + 1) . "
</td>
" . PHP_EOL;
        echo "
<td align=\"center\">
" . stripslashes($row['Patient_Name']) . "
</td>
" . PHP_EOL;
        echo "
<td>
" . stripslashes($row['Patient_IC']) . "
</td>
" . PHP_EOL;
        echo "
<td align=\"center\">
" . stripslashes($row['Phone']) . "
</td>
" . PHP_EOL;
        echo "
<td align=\"center\">
" . stripslashes($row['Address']) . "
</td>
" . PHP_EOL;
        echo "
<td align=\"center\">
" . stripslashes($row['Date_Admit']) . "
</td>
" . PHP_EOL;
        echo "
<td align=\"center\">
" . stripslashes($row['Date_Discharge']) . "
</td>
" . PHP_EOL;
        echo "
<td align=\"center\">
<button type=\"submit\"  name = \"deleteEntry\" value = \"" . stripslashes($row['Patient_ID']) . "\">
Delete
</button>
</td>
" . PHP_EOL;
        echo "
</tr>
" . PHP_EOL;
    }
}

echo "
</tbody>
</table>
";
echo "
</form>
";

$delete = NULL;
if (isset($_POST['deleteEntry'])) {
    $delete = $_POST['deleteEntry'];
}
$deletequery  = "DELETE FROM PATIENT
WHERE Patient_ID = $delete";
$deleteresult = $db->query($deletequery);

$result->free();
$db->close();
?>
```

UPDATE: I created another file called `delete.php` and change the post too.

```
<form action=\"delete.php\" method=\"post\">

<?php
@ $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'xxxx', 'xxxx', 'WARD');
 if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
     echo 'Error: Could not connect to database.  Please try again later.';
     exit;
 }

$delete = NULL; 
if(isset($_POST['deleteEntry'])){ $delete = $_POST['deleteEntry'];}
//$deletequery = "DELETE FROM PATIENT
//                  WHERE Patient_ID = $delete";
//$deleteresult = $db->query($deletequery);

mysqli_query($db,"DELETE FROM PATIENT
                    WHERE Patient_ID = $delete");

header ('Location: dbmgmt.php');
$result->free();
$db->close();
```

?>

Comment: what value u get for $_POST['deleteEntry'] ?

Comment: What error message comes back from MySQL? Could you echo out the SQL being executed and the error message? Also, you need to escape all values that get put into an SQL query. I suggest you use a prepared query: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: try to add hard coded value for deleting query ...

Comment: Umm i didnt check the output but i want to get the `Patient_ID`for that row... :( may be my algorithm or sequence is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query is deleting record from your table , but to see them you need to refresh page second time, because the select statment runs before the delete thats why you dont see that it deleted.

to avoid this better send the deletion to other page like delete.php.

EDIT: you can also use AJAX to delete them

EDIT2:

replace this :

```
  $delete = NULL;
 if (isset($_POST['deleteEntry'])) {
   $delete = $_POST['deleteEntry'];
}
  $deletequery  = "DELETE FROM PATIENT
 WHERE Patient_ID = $delete";
 $deleteresult = $db->query($deletequery);
```

by:

```
 if (isset($_POST['deleteEntry'])) {
    $delete = $_POST['deleteEntry'];

  $deletequery  = "DELETE FROM PATIENT WHERE Patient_ID = '".$delete."'  ";
  $deleteresult = $db->query($deletequery);
 }
```

Comment: hmm i tried moving the codes to `delete.php`. not working. :( is it my codes thats causing the problem? i've updated the codes.

Comment: :D oh yayyy it works!! thank you so much :D hmm didn't know string concatenation is important here cos the previous time i did that for UPDATE, it works :/